# How to calculate most congested roads from vehicle counts

Tags: count-data, density-function

I'm studying traffic flows, and I'd like to know what are the busiest/most congested roads. From this website http://www.dft.gov.uk/traffic-counts/about.php, it looks like vehicle counts are typically measured in AADF which is the Annual Average Daily Flow - the average number of vehicles that will travel between two checkpoints on an average day.

However, these AADFs are measured on road sections of varying lengths.

The website seems to think that "Traffic" ie AADF x road length (measured in vehicle miles) is a useful measurement, but what is this number actually useful for? If this is the case, a very sparse but long road would have the same value as a busy short road. It doesn't seem to make any sense using this definition of "traffic".

Surely, to figure out how congested a road is, you need to *divide* the AADF by the road length. Can anybody confirm this? Or make it clear how the AADF *is* useful? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you should divide by the length of the road. If there's a stretch of road one mile long which two cars enter/leave every minute, why would you want to say that was twice as busy as a stretch two miles long which two cars enter/leave every minute?  The two stretches could have the same number of cars on them per mile, travelling at the same speeds. The AADF itself seems to be the best measure of busyness available from the data, but congestion would be quite a jump from that - is there any info. on average speeds, speed limits, or number of lanes?